# InvocativeTargetException while trying to find .css file

Tags: java, css, file, javafx

I've tried around five different solutions from StackOverFlow and none of them work. I have a CSS file that I'm trying to apply to my GUI application by calling:

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());
```

My file system is as follows:

> myProject
>
> ------- src
>
> -------------- style.css
>
> -------------- package1
>
> --------------------- GUI.java  // <---- Class which needs style.css
>
> -------------- package2
>
> ------- bin

I've tried so many solutions already. I actually had this problem before where it would look in myProject/bin/ for the File. It's painfully frustrating. I don't want to strictly define the location because if the file ever moves or goes to a different computer, it would no longer work.

Comment: What's the exact exception. Please add stacktrace.

Comment: Exception in Application start method
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at application.GUI.start(GUI.java:224)

Comment: Always include the stack trace in your question (not in the comments). I assume line 224 is the line you posted...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming everything is deployed correctly, so you see style.css in the bin folder, you should be able to do either

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/style.css").toExternalForm());
```

(note the leading forward slash, `/`), or

```
scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm());
```

Comment: How do I deploy a text file resource to my program correctly? Currently there are no signs of style.css being in my bin/ folder.

Comment: Depends on your IDE. What are you using?

Comment: Eclipse. I changed things up and figured it'd be better to have a res folder since I've seen it suggested before. Here's my current file system: http://i.imgur.com/lrWFL4o.png

Comment: Go to Project on the menu, then Properties, and Java Build Path. Select the "Source" tab. You need the res folder listed under source folders, and with inclusion/exclusion rules that make sure everything you need is deployed.

Comment: Done: http://i.imgur.com/Ni0Oc0W.png . Howeve `scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("/res/style.css").toExternalForm());` Scene is also a non-null object, so it's not an external problem.

Comment: Try doing it like I suggested in the answer? Or just look at your bin folder, there will be no res folder inside it: style.css will be deployed to the root.

Comment: Wow... that worked. Okay so I guess anytime I have a file I need the program to work with, I have to make sure it's added in a source folder for Eclipse to recognize it?

Comment: Yes. I just put them in the regular src folder, but many people do recommend moving non-Java code resources into a separate resource folder. You just have to remember the application is going to look for the resources at *runtime*, so they need to be in the deployment hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

This should work,

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm()
```

You can also put the files in a package, like below

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("styles/style.css").toExternalForm()
```

where `styles` is the package name.

I suspect that you're using Eclipse IDE. Clean everything inside `/bin` folder and then rebuild your project (menu Project>Clean, Project>Build All or Project>Build Project).

This would place compiled classes and resource files(properties, css and all) in the `bin` directory.

**Note:** Remember `getClassLoader()` part is important. If it's not used and `getResource()` is directly called on the class then your resource file would be looked at a relative path to your class file. So if your class file is inside `foo.bar` package then following line

```
getClass().getResource("style.css").toExternalForm()
```

would look for file inside `foo/bar` folder, which you don't want. To avoid any confusion always use paths from the root and call `getResource()` of the `ClassLoader`